# codeigniter cookie expiry problem

Tags: codeigniter, cookies

I'm having a cookie issue, the expiry date on my cookie is always being set to At End Of Session which isn't what I want. I did a bit of goggling and it suggested it set the expire to time()+60*60*24*30 which I've done.

```
 //Create basket cookie
            $cookie = array(
                'name'   => 'basket_id',
                'value'  => $basket_id,
                'expire' => time()+60*60*24*30,
                'domain' => 'domain',
                'path'   => '/',
                'prefix' => '',
            );
            set_cookie($cookie);
```

I did wonder if it could be down to a Codeignter setting but my ci_session cookie has a normal expiry date. Thu, 09 Jun 2011 10:39:02 GMT

This is what I get when I view the cookie:

```
 Name   basket_id
 Value  28
 Host   .host
 Path   /
 Secure No
 Expires    At End Of Session
```

And here is an example of the array I'm passing to the cookie.

```
Array ( [name] => basket_id [value] => 30 [expire] => 1310202067 [domain] => host [path] => / [prefix] => )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out the [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29021501/revisions) by @Gowri for how to do it properly.

<s>You can try to adjust session expiration time in `config.php` CI session initially is saved in cookies:</s>

```
/** Session Variables
 ---------------------------------------
| 'session_expiration'  = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|  by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.
|
*/

$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question. Adjusting session expiration time is not really a solution as to why directly setting the cookie expiration variable doesn't result in an output that reflects the manually set cookie expiration date. Rather, read this solution, which worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15886879/1351605

Comment: I agree with you , what if you want to save some information that will persist, after the session expires, therefore , the answer is wrong, @sn0r answer was a better one.

Comment: it's not right answer, this answer is only confusing and distracting to all users, just edit it or delete it, it is not related to question anyway.

Comment: see the right answer below by @sn0r [https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021501/7719176](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29021501/7719176)

Answer (score 7):

Your expiry date is set incorrectly. **You don't have to include the time()**, as what you're setting is actually the expiry date from time().

When you have an incorrect expire value, it defaults to 0, which is set as your session's length instead.

Therefore it should be:

```
            $cookie = array(
            'name'   => 'basket_id',
            'value'  => $basket_id,
            'expire' => 86400*30,
            'domain' => 'domain',
            'path'   => '/',
            'prefix' => '',
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add params

```
$config['cookie_lifetime']  = 1800
```

in config.php, the reason you can find in libraries/Sessions/Session.php, code below

```
$expiration = config_item('sess_expiration');

if (isset($params['cookie_lifetime']))
{
    $params['cookie_lifetime'] = (int) $params['cookie_lifetime'];
}
else
{
    $params['cookie_lifetime'] = (!isset($expiration) && config_item('sess_expire_on_close'))
        ? 0 : (int) $expiration;
}
```