# Cookie expires on session out in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

I am setting a cookie in my codeigniter application using the following code. Working fine .. but cookie get expires on session out.. Please help

```
$cookie = array(
        'name'   => 'tvcUsername',
        'value'  => $email,
        'expire' => time()+86500,
        'domain' => 'http://localhost/tvc',
        'path'   => '/',
        'prefix' => '',

    );

    $this->input->set_cookie($cookie);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what do you mean "but cookie get expires on session out"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things I can think of:

a) localhost is not a valid domain, so cookies won't be saved for all browsers. Create yourself a HOST for "my.dev.server" or "localhost.dev" and point to 127.0.0.1  (you may also need to configure apache to respond to that name - but try it first just changing the HOSTS file first)

b) In addition, your "domain" includes a scheme and a path - that might be causing problems? Set to "localhost.dev" (drop the "http://" and the "/tvc" parts - once you've moved away from localhost.

Comment: thank you for your valuable points.. let me go through it and will get back to you .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The expiration is set in seconds, which will be added to the current time. **Do not include the time**, but rather only the number of seconds from now that you wish the cookie to be valid.

source: 
http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html