# losing cookie after closing the browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

```
         $value = array(
             'id'       => $data['id'] , 
             'username' => $data['username'] ,
             'email'    => $data['email'] ,
             'last_ip'  => $this->input->ip_address()

         );

         $value  = serialize($value);

         $cookie =  array (
             'name'   => 'is_logged' ,
             'value'  => $value ,
             'expire' => time()+86400 ,

         );

         set_cookie($cookie);
```

i have a function for checking the cookie

```
function get_k(){

   $k = get_cookie('is_logged'); 
    var_dump($k);

}
```

this works fine after login while the browser is still open , but if i close the browser , it doesn't work anymore

my config

```
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

i'm working on the localhost/firefox

Comment: Is your browser configured to remove cookies upon exit?

Comment: on your config did you set the config to remove cookies when browser is closed to true?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290502/codeigniter-cookie-expiry-problem

Comment: @tomexsans i dont think so , i didn't change anything it's on default settings  ... and i haven't seen any option for that ! i've posted my config

Comment: The config looks fine, see my answer and you will probably find that resolves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `time()` from the 'expire' value, CodeIgniter adds this automatically.

You also have a stray comma after 'expire'.

Comment: i'm going to try it but if this was the problem i wouldn't get to cookie while the browser is still open

Comment: Neither of those things matter.  He's adding a value to the time, so basically grabbing the current time and adding 86400 seconds.  Also, since the comma you pointed out is at the end of an array element, it won't cause any problems.

Comment: @Stanyer No, I wouldn't.  If this is a question regarding PHP, there are no issues.  If this is a question regarding CodeIgniter and those things cause an issue, then this is not a PHP question since the issue resides in the framework and not the language.

Comment: @cwscribner I didnt say it was an issue with PHP, I'm not sure why it does it (In CodeIgniter), but I'm sure it will resolve the problem as I've experienced it previously - so one of those things does matter, actually.